# When I use pally-ci with localhost I get NO errors, but external urls I get correct errors

Tags: continuous-integration, accessibility, pa11y

When I use pally-ci with localhost I get NO errors, but external urls I get correct errors and warnings.

Does anyone have this issue also.

my .pa11yci.js

```
module.exports = {
    urls: [
        'http://localhost:8080/#?mpb=topografie&mpz=11&mpv=52.3731081:4.8932945&pgn=home',
        'http://localhost:8080/#?dsd=bag&dsp=1&dsv=TABLE&mpb=topografie&mpz=11&mpv=52.3731081:4.8932945'
    ]
}
```

```

external:

```
module.exports = {
    urls: [
        'http://data.amsterdam.nl/#?mpb=topografie&mpz=11&mpv=52.3731081:4.8932945&pgn=home',
        'http://data.amsterdam.nl/#?dsd=bag&dsp=1&dsv=TABLE&mpb=topografie&mpz=11&mpv=52.3731081:4.8932945'
    ]
}
```

Comment: Did you ever get a solution for this issue?